# Special header with logo in center of it

Tags: header-footer

I would like to create header with logo in center

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\newcommand{\centerbox}[1]% #1 = text
{\bgroup% use local definitions
  \parskip=0pt
  \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}
  \dimen0=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\wd0\relax
  \par\noindent\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\box0\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\par
\egroup}

\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}

\newlength\TextBoxWd% width of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxSep% separation of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxHt% height of the text boxes

\setlength\TextBoxWd{\marginparwidth}
\setlength\TextBoxSep{\marginparsep}
\setlength\TextBoxHt{2cm}

\newcommand\ThickTitleRule{\xrfill[0.5ex]{3pt}}

\newcommand\Title[4]{%
\begingroup
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \par
  \makebox[\linewidth]{%
   % \fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#3}}\hspace{\TextBoxSep}%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
      \leavevmode
      \centering
      \ThickTitleRule\quad{\scshape\bfseries\itshape#1}\quad\ThickTitleRule\par
      \vskip-0.2\baselineskip
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par\vskip-.8\baselineskip% Thick horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%Thin horizontal line
      \par\vskip0.75ex
      {\Large\scshape\bfseries\itshape#2\par}% Title
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\par\vskip-.7\baselineskip% Thin horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}% Thick horizontal line
    }%
   % \hspace{\TextBoxSep}\fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#4}}\par%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip
\endgroup
}

%========================================================================================
\begin{document}

\Title{Mohcine}{The Kingdom of Morocco \hfill  
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=10cm,height=4cm]{1.jpg}
\end{center} \hfill Semester $1$\\
High School: Educ \hfill \hfill  Level: SM \\
\text{address, country} \hfill \hfill Year: 2016--2017 \\
 \textbf{Trainee Teacher :Educ \hfill  Mohcine}}}{}{}
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution based on `tabularx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, svgnames, demo]{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[english, french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,mathtools}
\newcommand{\centerbox}[1]% #1 = text
{\bgroup% use local definitions
  \parskip=0pt
  \sbox0{\fbox{#1}}
  \dimen0=\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth - 0.5\wd0\relax
  \par\noindent\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\box0\rule{\dimen0}{0.8pt}\par
\egroup}

\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
%\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit,calc,positioning}
  \tikzset{box/.style={draw, rectangle, thick, text centered, minimum height=3em}}
  \tikzset{line/.style={draw, thick, -latex'}}

\newlength\TextBoxWd% width of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxSep% separation of the text boxes
\newlength\TextBoxHt% height of the text boxes

\setlength\TextBoxWd{\marginparwidth}
\setlength\TextBoxSep{\marginparsep}
\setlength\TextBoxHt{2cm}

\newcommand\ThickTitleRule{\xrfill[0.5ex]{3pt}}

\newcommand\Title[4]{%
\begingroup
  \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
  \par
  \makebox[\linewidth]{%
   % \fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#3}}\hspace{\TextBoxSep}%
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{%
      \leavevmode
      \centering
      \ThickTitleRule\quad{\scshape\bfseries\itshape#1}\quad\ThickTitleRule\par
      \vskip-0.2\baselineskip
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\par\vskip-.8\baselineskip% Thick horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}%Thin horizontal line
      \par\vskip0.75ex
      {\Large\scshape\bfseries\itshape#2\par}% Title
      \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\par\par\vskip-.7\baselineskip% Thin horizontal line
      \rule{\textwidth}{2pt}% Thick horizontal line
    }%
   % \hspace{\TextBoxSep}\fbox{\parbox[t][\TextBoxHt][c]{\TextBoxWd}{\raggedright#4}}\par%
  }%
  \vskip\baselineskip
\endgroup
}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
%========================================================================================
\begin{document}
{\selectlanguage{english}
\Title{Mohcine}{\centering The Kingdom of Morocco\\[1.5ex]%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\raggedright\bfseries\arraybackslash}Xc>{\bfseries\arraybackslash}X@{}}
\makecell[lb]{High School: Educ\\
address, country\\
Trainee Teacher: \\%
Educ}%
 & \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth, height=4cm]{1.jpg}
 & \makecell[rb]{Semester 1\\%
Level: SM\\%
Year: 2016-2017\\%
Mohcine}
 \end{tabularx} }{}{}}
\bigskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why when i add image.jpg still drakness

Comment: Do you mean you still obtain a black rectangle? That is because I added the `[demo]` option for `graphicx`, as I didn't have the image. Just remove the option.

Comment: Thank you just i notice that i should add image with 100 pixels or i will get error that i have big image

Comment: The best thing to do is probably to fix a scaling rather than width and height (`\includegraphics[scale=…]{image}`).

Answer (score 3):

This should work :

```
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \fancypagestyle{logoheader}
 \fancyhead[LO,LE]{School \\ Adress \\ Teacher}
 \fancyhead[CO,CE]{\includegraphics{yourlogo}}
 \fancyhead[RO,RE]{Semester \\ Level \\ Year}
```

Then use `\pagestyle{logoheader}`.

You can customize it with some horizontal rules, it's easier than using tikz.

Comment: Obviously, if your logo is quite big, some tweakings should be made with `geometry" in order to find the right height for your header.